Should we rename [.net-5] to [.net-5.0]?
Can we rename .net-5 to .net-5.0 as a matter of consistency since every other .NET (I mean "actual" .NET, not .NET Core or .NET Framework) version number tag has .0 when possible :
.net-6.0, .net-7.0, .net-8.0 and .net-9.0 ?

is the .0 really needed? or are there tags also for the minor versions of .NET? (The same old discussion, how fine grained should version tags really be?)

@Lino I'm fine discussing removing the .0 part on 6, 7, 8 and 9 too. I'm really just looking for consistency. For the tags I know though (mostly C#/.NET) using .0 seems more common.
The only minor versions of .NET so far are all X.0.Y and there are no tags for these (and I don't think they'd be relevant)

It looks to me like Microsoft also refers to it as ".NET 5.0" (look under "Out of support versions").

I'd rather look under the major version than every minor version, IMHO.

At the moment all minor build numbers are not big releases. We haven't had a minor .NET version number since .NET Core 3.1 (and .NET Framework 4.8) which are actually major releases, but that may change in future, so makes sense to keep the .0 for consistency. Minor builds should not get their own tag unless they are a big release, with a What's New and Breaking Changes page in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-9/overview

The meanings of .NET 5 and .NET 5.0 should be different.

It looks to me like Microsoft refers to it at .NET 5

Imho, it does not matter, both tags are used for the same thing. Tag consistancy is overated unless you can show a real case where it would lead to a problem. I myself wouldn't have problems to use either tag. One possible scenario there this can be important would be if there was a rule, that X refers to any X.0, X.1.2, X.2.2.3, etc. while X.0 refers to any X.0.1, X.0.2, etc., then X and X.0 would be very different things. But I doubts that branches of versions will be useful (service support will like the idea, but not the users).

@Sinatr consistency is not overrated though. It doesn't matter what you think about the tag names, it is the act of sloppy bookkeeping which needs to be kept to a minimum and that begins with making sure people can't copy the wrong behavior.

@Gimby, you didn't demonstrate the problem. What behavior is wrong and why?

@IanKemp, go to tags page and search for "1.1". It looks like 5.0 is more consistent with StackOverflow than Microsoft's 5.

@RyanM ".NET 5.0" is the "product + version number", while ".NET 5" is the name. See this link - the URL says net-9.0 but the table says 9. ".NET 5.0" relates to ".NET 5" like "Windows NT 6.2" relates to "Windows 8", and I would assume we want a tag Windows 8 and not Windows NT 6.2.

Please don't; Microsoft themselves almost universally do not use the trailing .0 anywhere* for a good reason, because in a post-Framework post-Core world the release cycle has changed to an annual major version of .NET. In other words, the likelihood of a minor version ever being released going forward is almost nil.
Therefore, .net-5 is correct and .net-6.0, .net-7.0 etc. are not; it is the latter that should be renamed, not the former.
* A notable exception is their Downloads page for .NET but I believe this is due to the fact that the latter also lists the legacy Core products, which do have minor versions.

Upvoted solely for "don't bother" reasons. I don't see a problem here. There are many tags on StackOverflow which uses version with minors in tag name and as result there are dozens of "x-major.0" tags. OP may call this consistency and ask for tag renaming, then another guy comes with a better argument why it should be renamed other way around... while either tag name was already working for years and will continue working disregards.

Some searching suggests that Microsoft is not nearly consistent enough to justify "almost universally"; there is even at least one page that uses both.  I couldn't say with any certainty which is more prevalent, though.

I base my conclusion on what the devs themselves and people in the community use (e.g. on Github), and the .0 suffix is rare there. But trust Microsoft to muddle the waters more while trying to un-muddle them...

I posted a very long reply with a detailed suggestion which tags should exist and what they should refer to, in order to have them named

closely to what microsoft calls them
in a logical and predicatable pattern within technology families
in a way that avoids different techonologies have similar tag name patterns

By the way, this question around .net tags appears about once every year:

2017
2019
2021 (has my reply)
2022
2024 (this one)


I endorse your answer (on the question that I myself posted, LOL).
